# How to Search a String with spaces in between

Tags: vb.net

i am new to VB. so when i run my program and search for the name . i want to search with any spaces in between. For example i want to search "    Brian    Tracy" like that

i am quite confused on the string function that would do that. Thank you for your help

This is the code am working on

```
Dim search As String = txtAuthorsName.Text


'Search Sql For Authors Data
Dim conn As New     
OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                          Server.MapPath("~/Access/bookstore.accdb"))
conn.Open()

Dim sql As String = "SELECT AID, authorName, authorSex FROM Authors" 

Dim cmd As Object
If searchAuthor.SelectedValue.Equals("Name") Then
    If search.Length > 0 Then
       Dim keywords As String() = search.Split(" ")
       sql = "SELECT * FROM Authors where authorName like '%" & keywords(0) & "%'"
       For k As Integer = 1 To keywords.Length - 1
          sql += " or authorName Like '%" & keywords(k) & "%'"
       Next
    End If
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorName", "%" + txtAuthorsName.Text + "%")
Else
   sql += "WHERE authorSex LIKE @authorSex"
   cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorSex", "%" + txtAuthorSex.Text + "%")
End If

Dim dbread = cmd.ExecuteReader()
GridView2.DataSource = dbread
GridView2.DataBind()
dbread.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: If it is VB.NET (or it looks like it is) then it cannot be vba.  You might also want to look into the many, many other SQL operations besides `LIKE` such as `IN (, , ,)`.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Add a space before "WHERE": `sql += " WHERE authorSex LIKE @authorSex"`. You don't have an `@authorName` parameter. `like '%something%'` already works with leading and trainling spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how to filter/search data :

```
  Public Sub FilterData(valueToSearch As String)
    '
    Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From Users WHERE CONCAT(fname, lname, age) like '%" & valueToSearch & "%'"

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, connection)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable()

    adapter.Fill(table)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = table

End Sub

Private Sub BTN_FILTER_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_FILTER.Click

    FilterData(TextBox1.Text)
```

Make necessary changes, hope it works